# Gaming in Facebook for Android

Tags: android, facebook, game-development

I've developed a Facebook application for Android.
For further development, I would like to know whether I can enhance it  to add gaming features of Facebook in it. Is there a flash player that I can use for it? Please reply ASAP....

Comment: What specific features are you talking about?

Comment: Features as in when a friend has uploaded a game on his profile we should be able to play it in our android application.

Answer (score 1):

Flash 10.1 will be released for Android 2.0+ in first half of 2010 ref http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/features.html

However, it will not necessarily be easily integrated with your existing Java based application.